# Find the largest number in an array of integers javascript

Tags: javascript, html, integer, syntax-error

Hi my knowledge on javascript and I have been getting help on here which was quite helpful (thanks everybody!) but it is still very limited and basic. Basically below is I will prompt a pop-up that displays the answer to the value. The thing is from the coding I found below if I had to insert an array lets say `12,8,3,2` the output would be `8`. For some reason the code below is only taking into consideration 1 digits. Is there a way to edit this code so that the answer to the input above would be `12`.

Thanks once again!

I have done my fair share of research:

**Code:**

```
<html><head>

  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>test</title>


</head><body>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function evaluate() {
  const input = prompt("Please enter the array of integers in the form: 1,2,3,1")
    .split(',')
    .map(nums => nums.trim());

  function max(numArray) 
{
    var nums = numArray.slice();
    if (nums.length == 1) { return nums[0]; }
    if (nums[0] < nums[1]) { nums.splice(0,1); }
    else { nums.splice(1,1); }
    return max(nums);
}


  if (input == "" || input == null) {
            document.writeln("Sorry, there is nothing that can be calculated.");
        } else {    

  document.writeln("The largest number is: ");
  document.writeln(max(input) + " with a starting input string of: " + input);
}
}
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    evaluate();
  </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: what input did you gave in the prompt box?

Comment: One small change will fix it...  `.map(nums => number(nums.trim()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing string not integers. Therefore it only compares the first character of the 'digits' which in your case 12 vs 8 will result to 8 being greater than 1 (the first character of 12). Before doing the comparison make sure to change the string to an integer. All you need to change is one line:

`if (nums[0] < nums[1])` to

`if (parseInt(nums[0]) < parseInt(nums[1]))`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omartanti/ahbtg2z2/1/

**Please Note: parseInt returns NaN if the first character cannot be converted to a number**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.max(...array)` function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

```
const returnMax = (str='') => { // pass string
    const numbersArr = str.trim().split(',').map(num => parseInt(num.trim()));
    return Math.max(...numbersArr); // rest-spread operator from es6 syntax
}
```

More about rest operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: Hi thanks but it must make use of recursion. I didnt specify in the title. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.max` and spread operator `(...)` to get the max value.In the snippet `+num.trim()` will convert string to number

```js
function evaluate() {
  const input = prompt("Please enter the array of integers in the form: 1,2,3,1")
    .split(',')
    .map(nums => +nums.trim());
  console.log(input)
  var getLargest = Math.max(...input);
  console.log(getLargest)
}

evaluate();
```

Comment: Hi thanks but it must make use of recursion. I didnt specify in the title. Thanks though